# Tower of Hanoi in NASM Win64 Assembly

Tags: game, recursion, windows, assembly, nasm

This program is an implementation of the classic puzzle [Tower of Hanoi](http://www.towerofhanoi.org/)! This is my first mostly recursive Assembly program. Any advice and all topical comments on code optimization and conventions is appreciated!

---

Compiled as follows using `VS2017 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`:

> ```
> > nasm -g -fwin64 hanoi.asm
>
> > cl /Zi hanoi.obj msvcrt.lib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
> ```

**hanoi.asm**

```
;; bits 64
default rel

extern printf, scanf

section .text
    global main
    global hanoi
main:
    sub     rsp, 56
    lea     rcx, [prompt]
    call    printf
    lea     rdx, [rsp+32]
    lea     rcx, [scan_fmt]
    call    scanf
    cmp     eax, 1
    jz      .call_hanoi
    lea     rcx, [scan_fail]
    call    printf
    mov     eax, 1                      ; return 1
.end:
    add     rsp, 56
    ret
.call_hanoi:
    mov     ecx, dword [rsp+32]         ; ecx = num_disks
    mov     r9d, 3                      ; r9d = tmp
    mov     r8d, 2                      ; r8d = dst
    mov     edx, 1                      ; edx = src
    call    hanoi                       ; hanoi(num_disks, src, dst, tmp)
    xor     eax, eax                    ; return 0
    jmp     .end
hanoi:
    push    r12
    mov     r12d, r8d                   ; r12d = r8d = dst
    push    rbp
    push    rdi
    push    rsi
    mov     esi, edx                    ; esi = edx = src
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 40
    cmp     ecx, 1                      ; if num_disks == 1
    jz      .skip_recursive_move
    mov     ebx, ecx
    mov     edi, r9d                    ; edi = r9d = tmp
.move_disk:
    lea     ebp, [rbx-1H]               ; ebp = num_disks - 1
    mov     r9d, r12d                   ; r9d = r12d = dst
    mov     r8d, edi                    ; r8d = edi = tmp
    mov     edx, esi                    ; edx = esi = src
    mov     ecx, ebp                    ; ecx = edp = num_disks - 1
    call    hanoi                       ; tmp & dst are swapped for this call
    mov     edx, ebx                    ; edx = ebx = num_disks
    mov     r9d, r12d                   ; update r9d after hanoi call
    mov     r8d, esi                    ; update r8d after hanoi call
    lea     rcx, [prompt_move_disk]
    mov     ebx, ebp                    ; ebx = ebp = num_disks - 1
    call    printf
    cmp     ebp, 1                      ; if num_disks == 1
    jz      .move_one_disk
    mov     eax, esi
    mov     esi, edi
    mov     edi, eax                    ; swaps tmp and src (esi and edi)
    jmp     .move_disk
.skip_recursive_move:
    mov     edi, edx                    ; edi = edx = src
.move_one_disk:
    add     rsp, 40
    mov     r8d, r12d
    mov     edx, edi
    pop     rbx
    lea     rcx, [prompt_move_one_disk]
    pop     rsi
    pop     rdi
    pop     rbp
    pop     r12
    jmp     printf

%macro str 2
    %2: db %1, 0
%endmacro

section .rdata
    str "How many disks do you want to play with? ", prompt
    str "%u", scan_fmt
    str {"Uh-oh, I couldn't understand that...  No towers of Hanoi for you!", 10}, scan_fail
    str {"Move disk 1 from %d to %d", 10}, prompt_move_one_disk
    str {"Move disk %d from %d to %d", 10}, prompt_move_disk
```

**Sample output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Observations.

> ```
> Move disk 1 from 1 to 3
> Move disk 2 from 1 to 2
> ```

I think these messages would be more descriptive (less ambiguous) if you included the word *peg*:

*Move disk 1 from peg 1 to peg 3*
*Move disk 2 from peg 1 to peg 2*

---

> ```
> mov     r9d, r12d                   ; update r9d after hanoi call
> mov     r8d, esi                    ; update r8d after hanoi cal
> ```

I found it confusing to read these comments. Registers `R8D` and `R9D` are being setup for the upcoming *printf* and nothing else. The mention of *"update after hanoi call"* would suggest they have a more permanent significance which they haven't.

### Optimizations.

- The *.skip_recursive_move* operation for when `ECX` is 1 on input can be much simpler. All registers are already conveniently setup for the tailcall (`jmp`) to *printf*.
- The program uses the `EBP` register in a redundant fashion and hence you can shave off a number of instructions. You also no longer need to preserve `EBP`.

I suggest you take a look at my version below:

```
hanoi:
    cmp     ecx, 1                      ; if num_disks == 1
    je      .skip_recursive_move

    push    rbx
    push    rsi
    push    rdi
    push    r12

    mov     ebx, ecx                    ; ECX=2+
    mov     esi, edx                    ; esi = edx = src
    mov     edi, r9d                    ; edi = r9d = tmp
    mov     r12d, r8d                   ; r12d = r8d = dst

.move_disk:
    mov     r9d, r12d                   ; dst
    mov     r8d, edi                    ; tmp
    mov     edx, esi                    ; src
    lea     ecx, [rbx - 1]              ; num_disks - 1
    call    hanoi                       ; tmp & dst are swapped for this call

    mov     r9d, r12d                   ; the 'to' peg
    mov     r8d, esi                    ; the 'from' peg
    mov     edx, ebx                    ; num_disks
    lea     rcx, [prompt_move_disk]
    call    printf

    dec     ebx                         ; num_disks - 1
    cmp     ebx, 1                      ; if num_disks == 1
    je      .move_one_disk

    mov     eax, esi
    mov     esi, edi
    mov     edi, eax                    ; swaps tmp and src (esi and edi)
    jmp     .move_disk

.move_one_disk:
    mov     r8d, r12d                   ; the 'to' peg
    mov     edx, edi                    ; the 'from' peg

    pop     r12
    pop     rdi
    pop     rsi
    pop     rbx

.skip_recursive_move:
    lea     rcx, [prompt_move_one_disk]
    jmp     printf
```

Please notice that setting up the calling registers in a consistent order (`RCX`, `RDX`, `R8`, `R9`) helps to improve readability. Leaving a blank line further groups things into logical blocks.

One additional optimization comes from exchanging `ESI`and `EDI` regardless, thus being able to re-arrange the code to avoid having 2 jump instructions:

```
    ...
    mov     eax, esi
    mov     esi, edi
    mov     edi, eax                    ; swaps tmp and src (esi and edi)

    dec     ebx                         ; num_disks - 1
    cmp     ebx, 1                      ; if num_disks == 1
    jne     .move_disk

    mov     r8d, r12d                   ; the 'to' peg
    mov     edx, ESI                    ; the 'from' peg
    ...
```

See that this time `ESI` gives the 'from' peg!

**EDIT (copy-paste version)**:

```
;; bits 64
default rel

extern printf, scanf

section .text
    global main
    global hanoi
main:
    sub     rsp, 56
    lea     rcx, [prompt]
    call    printf
    lea     rdx, [rsp+32]
    lea     rcx, [scan_fmt]
    call    scanf
    cmp     eax, 1
    jz      .call_hanoi
    lea     rcx, [scan_fail]
    call    printf
    mov     eax, 1                      ; return 1
.end:
    add     rsp, 56
    ret
.call_hanoi:
    mov     ecx, dword [rsp+32]         ; ecx = num_disks
    mov     r9d, 3                      ; r9d = tmp
    mov     r8d, 2                      ; r8d = dst
    mov     edx, 1                      ; edx = src
    call    hanoi                       ; hanoi(num_disks, src, dst, tmp)
    xor     eax, eax                    ; return 0
    jmp     .end
hanoi:
    cmp     ecx, 1                      ; if num_disks == 1
    je      .skip_recursive_move

    push    rbx
    push    rsi
    push    rdi
    push    r12

    mov     ebx, ecx                    ; ECX=2+
    mov     esi, edx                    ; esi = edx = src
    mov     edi, r9d                    ; edi = r9d = tmp
    mov     r12d, r8d                   ; r12d = r8d = dst

.move_disk:
    mov     r9d, r12d                   ; dst
    mov     r8d, edi                    ; tmp
    mov     edx, esi                    ; src
    lea     ecx, [rbx - 1]              ; num_disks - 1
    call    hanoi                       ; tmp & dst are swapped for this call

    mov     r9d, r12d                   ; the 'to' peg
    mov     r8d, esi                    ; the 'from' peg
    mov     edx, ebx                    ; num_disks
    lea     rcx, [prompt_move_disk]
    sub     rsp, 32                     ;shadow space
    call    printf
    add     rsp, 32

    mov     eax, esi
    mov     esi, edi
    mov     edi, eax                    ; swaps tmp and src (esi and edi)

    dec     ebx                         ; num_disks - 1
    cmp     ebx, 1                      ; if num_disks == 1
    jne     .move_disk

    mov     r8d, r12d                   ; the 'to' peg
    mov     edx, esi                    ; the 'from' peg

    pop     r12
    pop     rdi
    pop     rsi
    pop     rbx

.skip_recursive_move:
    lea     rcx, [prompt_move_one_disk]
    sub     rsp, 32                     ;shadow space
    call    printf
    add     rsp, 32
    ret

%macro str 2
    %2: db %1, 0
%endmacro

section .rdata
    str "How many disks do you want to play with? ", prompt
    str "%u", scan_fmt
    str {"Uh-oh, I couldn't understand that...  No towers of Hanoi for you!", 10}, scan_fail
    str {"Move disk 1 from peg %d to peg %d", 10}, prompt_move_one_disk
    str {"Move disk %d from peg %d to peg %d", 10}, prompt_move_disk
```

Comment: Could you put all of your optimizations in one complete program? Trying to put things together gave me this instruction: `Moving disk 707448147 from peg 1 to peg 7074481471`.

Comment: @T145 *printf*'s shadow space was missing.